# C# event when SQL is updated

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am working with multiple desktop applications, and I want them to update when a new row is added to a table.  Currently, I am constantly querying SQL to see if it is up to date, but this feels like a non scalable approach.

Is there a way to set up an event which listens for a database update?

Comment: what is the database here? this would be an implementation-specific feature, and most: don't implement something like that - but some might; we'd need to know what you're using, though! most commonly, people track something like the last known id/rowversion/time, or use checksum_agg, though

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server using entity framework

Comment: Perhaps the `SqlDependency` class?